# How to select class[array] in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have elements like this...

```
<input type="text" name="name-lang[en]" id="name-lang[en]"> Name in English
<input type="text" name="name-lang[fr]" id="name-lang[fr]"> Name in France
```

And my jQuery is...

```
$('#name-lang[en]').hide();
```

which is not work.
And this is not work too.

```
$('#name-lang\[en\]').hide();
```

These are elements for html 5.

Comment: why u dont give them a class?

Comment: That id is invalid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: From your linked question: *"HTML 5 is even more permissive, saying only that an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters."*

Comment: Nope, i don't think it is invalid in html 5. You may test it yourself with this html.<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="name-lang[en]">
</body>
</html>

and go to test here. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input
and the result is `Passed, 2 warning(s)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `\` is the escape character in strings, `'#name-lang\[en\]'` is equivalent to `'#name-lang[en]'`:

```js
> console.log('#name-lang\[en\]');
#name-lang[en]
```

You have to escape the `\` as well:

```
$('#name-lang\\[en\\]')
```

If you don't want to escape the characters, you can use the attribute selector with a quoted value:

```
$('input[id="name-lang[en]"]')
$('input[name="name-lang[en]"]')
```

---

This is well explained in the [**jQuery documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ `` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

Comment: The id i use is invalid but thank you, your answer works fine.

Comment: @vee: It's invalid in HTML4 but not in HTML5.

Comment: I remember writing up that documentation years ago, when we ran into IDs being generated from a CMS and being outside of our control, IIRC. *sniff* Memories.

Comment: @ajm: If only more people would read documentation :-) :-/ :-(

Comment: ``<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><!-- <!DOCTYPE html> --> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>test</title> </head> <body> <input type="text" id="name-lang[en]"> </body> </html>`` 
tested and it is passed!
Thanks @FelixKling

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
$('input[name=name-lang\\[en\\]]')
```

but anyway, it's wrong approach: 1) to have ID of element be exactly the same as NAME attribute; 2)use additional [] in ID w/o special need